# How can an e-commerce website be built without using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, e-commerce

Since I read [this article](http://www.wired.com/2015/11/i-turned-off-javascript-for-a-whole-week-and-it-was-glorious/) I've been intrigued about the possibility of building a modern website without using JS. Apparently it's possible by using php or only html (like in 90s). Is there any alternative way to them, to build an e-commerce website without any JS involved? What languages can be used for that purpose? Any widely used websites built without JS?

Comment: Yes, with a loooot of page reloads...

Comment: Lots of Google services (like Google Search or Gmail) works without JS, so it's possible.

Comment: If you have the knowledge to perform a large part of what JS can do in CSS (or if you'd rather avoid fanciness completely), then its perfectly reasonable to do it, but... Why? The existence of these languages is to make things easier/nicer for the developers. I completely understand where the editor is coming from, I bet it was glorious, but as they then go on to say, nothing worked. Because everyone uses JS, because its great to use. PHP is even more of a monster then JS (so that's probably not a reasonable comparison).

Comment: Yes there are e-commerce sites that run without js being required.

Comment: @cartalot, do you have any example of e-commerce sites built without JS?

Comment: an e-commerce website has to remember who you are in order to show you the shopping cart and to checkout. thats either done with cookies or a session token so no js is needed. to process the credit card transaction some processors like stripe require a js script, but there are processors that do not require a js script. otherwise all validation should be done server side, so js is just there to help, and for the front end (design).

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to build an e-commerce website without javascript, but (most would say) not advisable.

You can also build a website without CSS, but it will not look great. You can build a website without Javascript, but your interactions will not be great. On most websites, Javascript is used to manipulate the DOM and transfer information without having to load a new page.

HTML creates the structure that holds the content. Sometimes, Javascript is used to create this.

CSS modifies the styles of the HTML elements. Sometimes, Javascript is used to do this as well, especially in response to an event.

PHP tells the HTML what content belongs in the structure. Sometimes, Javascript is used send information that is handled by PHP.

In each of these scenarios, a new page would be required to make changes without JS, either by reloading or changing the current page. Javascript lessens the burden of manually loading this content.

Comment: So in your opinion not using JS doesn't improve page load time as the pages will need to reload and that will be more burden than loading JS?

Comment: with respect  - everything you are mentioning could apply to any website because your examples are for the "front end". there is nothing specific for e-commerce needs like the shopping cart or checkout. js is only required if a merchant wants to use Stripe or similar service for payment processing because the transaction info is sent via the stripe js file.